# How to order or filter entries by their author's custom field?

Tags: plugin-development, filter, ordering, order, filtering

Is it possible to order and/or filter all entries from a section whose author has a custom field value that is set to "X"?

Below is the starting code.

in Twig:

```
{% set elementQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('sectionHandle')
    .with(['author'])
%}
```

in PHP:

```
$elementQuery = Entry::find()
    ->section('sectionHandle')
    ->with(['author']);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This requires a bit of extra work on the ElementQuery, but it can be efficiently done in the same query.

We first perform an inner join on the author's content table using the `authorId` so that the custom field is available to us.

in Twig:

```
{% set elementQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('sectionHandle')
    .with(['author'])
    .innerJoin('{{%content}} author_content', '[[author_content.elementId]] = [[authorId]]')
    .andWhere({'author_content.field_customFieldHandle': 'X'})
%}
```

in PHP:

```
$elementQuery = Entry::find()
    ->section('sectionHandle')
    ->with(['author'])
    ->innerJoin('{{%content}} author_content', '[[author_content.elementId]] = [[authorId]]')
    ->andWhere(['author_content.field_customFieldHandle' => 'X']);
```

---

To order by a custom field we use `orderBy`.

in Twig:

```
{% set elementQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('sectionHandle')
    .with(['author'])
    .innerJoin('{{%content}} author_content', '[[author_content.elementId]] = [[authorId]]')
    .orderBy('author_content.field_customFieldHandle asc')
%}
```

in PHP:

```
$elementQuery = Entry::find()
    ->section('sectionHandle')
    ->with(['author'])
    ->innerJoin('{{%content}} author_content', '[[author_content.elementId]] = [[authorId]]')
    ->orderBy('author_content.field_customFieldHandle asc');
```

---

To filter by a custom field we add `andWhere`.

in Twig:

```
{% set elementQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('sectionHandle')
    .with(['author'])
    .innerJoin('{{%content}} author_content', '[[author_content.elementId]] = [[authorId]]')
    .andWhere({'author_content.field_customFieldHandle': 'X'})
%}
```

in PHP:

```
$elementQuery = Entry::find()
    ->section('sectionHandle')
    ->with(['author'])
    ->innerJoin('{{%content}} author_content', '[[author_content.elementId]] = [[authorId]]')
    ->andWhere(['author_content.field_customFieldHandle' => 'X']);
```